# How to change the values of a tensor row-wise based on predefined row indices

Tags: python, tensorflow

Consider I have a tensor called `x` which has the shape of `[1, batch_size]`. I want to change the rows of another tensor called `my_tensor` with the shape of `[batch_size, seq_length]` if the respected value in `x` is less than or equal to zero.

I suppose I can explain better by representing a code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 3
seq_length = 5

x = tf.constant([-1, 4, 0]) # size is [1, batch_size]

# select the indices of the rows to be changed
candidate_rows = tf.where(tf.less_equal(x, 0))

my_tensor = tf.random.uniform(shape=(batch_size, seq_length), minval=10, maxval=30, seed=123)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(sess.run(candidate_rows))
print(sess.run(my_tensor))
```

which will produce:

```
candidate_rows = 
 [[0]
  [2]]

my_tensor = 
 [[10.816193 14.168425 11.83606  24.044014 24.146267]
 [17.929298 11.330187 15.837727 10.592653 29.098463]
 [10.122135 16.338099 24.35467  15.236387 10.991222]]
```

and I would like to change rows [0] and [2] in my tensor to another value, say all equal to 1.

```
 [[1 1 1 1]
 [17.929298 11.330187 15.837727 10.592653 29.098463]
 [1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Perhaps all the problem arises when I use the `tf.where`. I appreciate any assistance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to your problem is to use `tf.where` to select between elements of two tensors.

```
t = tf.ones(shape=my_tensor.shape, dtype=my_tensor.dtype)
my_tensor = tf.where(x > 0, my_tensor, t)
```